# Customizing the apps script add-ons menu for each editor

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, gsuite-addons

I've got an add-on that previously only targeted Google Docs, and I'm trying to expand the feature set to include Google Sheets. In development mode, I can set a conditional to detect which document type is active (docs or sheets) and then show the corresponding menu.  When I publish the latest version of the add-on, the add-on menu stops working in both Docs and Sheets.

I'm guessing it has to do with the permissions around "onOpen()" but i'm not sure how else to handle this.  The G Suite Marketplace allows you to designate that an add-on supports multiple editors.

Here's the code that works in development:

```
function onOpen(e) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();

  if(ss != null && ss != undefined) {
    var sheetsUI = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    sheetsUI.createAddonMenu()
      .addItem('Name', 'function')
      .addToUi();
  }

  if(doc != null && doc != undefined) {
    var docsUI = DocumentApp.getUi();

    docsUI.createAddonMenu()
    .addItem('Name', 'function')
    .addToUi();
  }  
}
```

If I remove the conditional stuff, and only include editor specific menu (docs for docs, sheets for sheets), the menus appear correctly.

Comment: If you think it's a permissions issue then try an installable onOpen

Comment: Hello @Eli, which type of trigger is `onOpen` on your project? Please bear in mind that the simple `onOpen` trigger fires automatically, without asking the user for authorization - which may be the cause of your issue. Have you tried using an installable trigger, just like @Cooper has mentioned? Cheers!

Comment: Thanks to both of you.  I tried this route, but it wasn't the solution. It turned out that my conditional checks were throwing an error, and the solution was inspired by @alan wells's below - to wrap the menus in try/catch blocks.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't want the user to need to approve access to their Sheets, if it's a Docs add-on and vice versa.  And if the add-on doesn't have permission to one of them then your code would throw an error, so you need to trap the error with a `try/catch`

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var docUI,thisIsA_Sheet;

  try{
    docUI = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    thisIsA_Sheet = true;
  }catch(e){
    //Do nothing
  }

  if (!thisIsA_Sheet) {//This is not a Google Sheet
    try{
      docUI = DocumentApp.getUi();
    }catch(e){
      //Do nothing
    }
  }

  docUI.createAddonMenu()
    .addItem('Name', 'function')
    .addToUi();

}
```

Comment: Thank you, Alan!  This suggestion led me to the solution.  My original code was throwing an error.  I placed each menu item inside a try/catch block, and it now works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The comment about trapping errors led me to the solution. I placed each editor's menu code inside try/catch blocks, and now it works.

```
function onOpen(e) {

  try{
    var docsUI = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    docsUI.createAddonMenu()
    .addItem('Sheets menu item name', 'function')
    .addToUi();
  } catch(e) {
  }

  try{
    var docsUI = DocumentApp.getUi();
    docsUI.createAddonMenu()
    .addItem('Docs menu item name', 'function')
    .addToUi();
  } catch(e) {
  } 

}
```